# how to use 2 (or more) CCSpriteBatchNode's instances

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccspritebatchnode

I decided to have some practice with BatchNodes, but I'm stuck
here is some code:

```
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"scene1atlas.plist"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"CloudsAtlas.plist"];

        sceneSpriteBatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"scene1atlas.png"];
        cloudSpriteBatchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"CloudsAtlas.png"];

[self addChild:sceneSpriteBatchNode z:20];
[self addChild:cloudSpriteBatchNode z:21];

SomeGameObject *gameObject = [[SomeGameObject alloc]
                         initWithSpriteFrameName:@"sv_anim_1.png"];
gameObject.texture=[sceneSpriteBatchNode texture];

[sceneSpriteBatchNode addChild:gameObject
                                     z:1000 tag:kGameObjectTagValue];

*** Assertion failure in -[GameObject setTexture:]
```

How to set texture properly?

Comment: set texture is not necessary, the sprite uses the sprite frame's texture

Comment: Thanks for reply. if i do not set texture, message 'CCSprite is not using the same texture id'. but if i put gameObject into layer [self addChild:..], it goes fine.

Comment: Then the sprite frame "sv_anim_1.png" is not part of the "scene1atlas.png" texture atlas. Sprite and batch node must use the same texture. For example if "sv_anim_1.png" is in "CloudsAtlas.png" then you have to add that sprite to cloudSpriteBatchNode.